# find usage of string in symfony code programatically

Tags: php, reflection, symfony

I'm working on a bundle that provide parameters management (a simple key|value table for the beginning).

I would like to be able to tell people before they delete a parameter that the parameter is used.

For example: I have a parameter `mykey = "hello world"` defined in my table.

In another bundle, I use the variable like this:

```
$this->get("my.parameters")->getValue("mykey","myDefaultValue","myContext");
```

If the user wants to edit or delete `mykey` I would like to tell him that in the code, this variable is used (and if possible, give him the context).

The parameters will be used in controllers and services. How can I do that?

Comment: For me it is useless. You "users" are developers not users. Or define a method that will raise an exception if the parameter key is not found.

Comment: Are you talking about deleting a parameter using a web interface or do you mean deleting it in the code?

Comment: instead of using a simple string, why not using something like an enum?

Comment: @COil the variables can be modified by users. I want to tell my users that the vars are in use in the declared context.

Comment: @mickadoo yes, through a web interface

Comment: @LBA it doesn't contains only a string. the value can be an array or anything else.

Comment: I don't know of a way that the parameter bag is aware of how and where it is being used. I thought there might be static analysis available through Java, but even PhpStorm doesn't seem to have a "find usages" for parameters. My only suggestion would be to prefix parameters names with a unique string and from there you can do a regex over all your project files for places where it occurs. Using this method you could also get the context. Edit: but it seems slow and messy

Comment: but still you could use some static classes or something else. using a 'string' as an identifier is always tricky.

Comment: Why would they need unused parameters?